# Linq to XML, force a closing and opening tag between an already existing tag

Tags: xml, linq

There is a tag for example

```
<book>
<firstHalf>  </firstHalf>

<secondHalf>   </second half>
</book>
```

my requirement is I need to seprate firsthalf and second half as such below

```
<book>
<firstHalf>  </firstHalf>
</book>
<book>
<secondHalf> </second half>
</book>
```

so first I need to add a new closing book tag then a opening book tag! p- Using linq

I am not sure how to do it, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: its not a valid XML..`second half` should be `secondHalf`

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var xmlStr = @"<root>
    <book>
        <firstHalf></firstHalf>
        <secondHalf></secondHalf>
    </book>
</root>
";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);

// find all books
var books = doc.Descendants("book").ToList();
    // p.s., need ToList() since we're modifying the structure
foreach (var book in books)
{
    // get all the "extra" elements
    var extraElements = book.Elements().Skip(1).ToList();
    if (extraElements.Any())
    {
        // remove the extra elements from the current book
        extraElements.Remove();
        // create new books after this book with the extra element
        book.AddAfterSelf(extraElements.Select(e => new XElement("book", e)));
    }
}
```

Yields:

```xml
<root>
  <book>
    <firstHalf></firstHalf>
  </book>
  <book>
    <secondHalf></secondHalf>
  </book>
</root>
```